# How to detect intersection of two faces in 3D

Tags: c++, 3d, intersection, plane, face

lets say

```
struct myFace
{
    3DPoint p0;
    3DPoint p1;
    3DPoint p2;
    3DPoint p3;
    3DPoint pNormal;

};
```

face1 and face2 is faces which type of myFace.

```
double ac = face1.pNormal * face2.pNormal;
```

if (!(ac<1.00000001 && ac>0.99999999) && !(ac>-1.00000001 && ac<-0.99999999))

then faces are not parallel.

but how can detect if they do intersect or do not ?

Comment: Since you have 4 points this becomes quite complex. The general way to do this is to first compute the infinite line at the intersection of the two planes, then compute the sets of points which this line intersects both faces, then see if these sets overlap. I'll try to come up with a more complete answer later.

Comment: thanks. i will wait for your complete answer.

Comment: are the points defined in anticlockwise / clockwise fashion? I'll assume they are (and they should be)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops ignore my comment: thought of another way to do this.

---

- Step 1:

For faces `F1` and `F2`, take `F2`'s points as two *triangles*, e.g. `(p0, p1, p2)` and `(p1, p2, p3)` respectively. Then take `F1`'s edges, i.e. `(p0, p1)`, `(p1, p2)`, `(p2, p3)`, and `(p3, p0)`, then intersect each of them with both of the triangles.

I found some code to do this: (adapted from http://geomalgorithms.com/a06-_intersect-2.html)

```
#define SMALL_NUM   0.00000001

/* 
   returns: 0 if no intersection 
            1 if parallel but disjoint
            2 if coplanar
*/
int intersect3D_RayTriangle(Vector P0, Vector P1, Vector V0, Vector V1, Vector V2)
{
    Vector    u, v, n;              // triangle vectors
    Vector    dir, w0, w;           // ray vectors
    float     r, a, b;              // params to calc ray-plane intersect

    // get triangle edge vectors and plane normal
    u = V1 - V0;
    v = V2 - V0;
    n = cross(u, v);

    dir = P1 - P0;             // ray direction vector
    w0 = P0 - V0;
    a = -dot(n, w0);
    b = dot(n, dir);
    if (fabs(b) < SMALL_NUM)   // ray is parallel to triangle plane
        return (fabs(a) < SMALL_NUM ? 2 : 0);

    // get intersect point of ray with triangle plane
    r = a / b;
    if (r < 0.0 || r > 1.0)
        return 0;                   // => no intersect
    Vector I = R.P0 + r * dir;      // intersect point of ray and plane

    // is I inside T?
    float uu, uv, vv, wu, wv, D;
    uu = dot(u, u);
    uv = dot(u, v);
    vv = dot(v, v);
    w = I - V0;
    wu = dot(w, u);
    wv = dot(w, v);
    D = uv * uv - uu * vv;

    // get and test parametric coords
    float s, t;
    s = (uv * wv - vv * wu) / D;
    if (s < 0.0 || s > 1.0)         // I is outside T
        return 0;
    t = (uv * wu - uu * wv) / D;
    if (t < 0.0 || (s + t) > 1.0)  // I is outside T
        return 0;

    return 1;                       // I is in T
}
```

`P0` and `P1` form one of the edges from `F1`, while `V0`, `V1` and `V2` form one the `F2`'s triangles.

- If one of the checks (there should be 8) returns 1, then they definitely intersect (return true *immediately*).
- If *all* of them return 0, then they don't intersect.
- If one of the checks returns 2 (the first check will probably do that) then we need a different method. Stop these checks and *immediately* move onto step 2.

---

- Step 2:

This part is for if the polygons are coplanar (i.e. parallel and in the same plane). This time, take all of `F1`'s edges and all of `F2`'s edges; for each of `F1`'s edges, check if it intersects with any of `F2`'s edges, and if one pair intersects then return true *immediately*.

To do such an edge intersection: (adapted from https://gist.github.com/hanigamal/6556506)

`A0`, `A1` form the edge from `F1`, and `B0`, `B1` from `F2`.

```
int intersection(Vector A0, Vector A1, Vector B0, Vector B1)
{
   Vector dA = A1 - A0;
   Vector dB = B1 - B0;
   Vector dC = B0 - A0;

   double s = dot(cross(dC, dB), cross(dA, dB)) / norm2(cross(dA, dB));
    return (s >= 0.0 && s <= 1.0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you . I also thought about ray-triangle algoritms but I did not know ray triangle works with finite rays. I will try it. Thank you again.

Comment: @siyah working with finite rays is really no more complicated than infinite rays - but you need to parameterize it and place a limit the corresponding parameter